# Tableau checkbox filter to suppress zero rows

Tags: reporting, tableau-api, business-intelligence

I'm pretty new to Tableau, and am unsure how to implement a feature that's been requested by business users.

We have a report where each row has

- `Owner` - grouping text field
- `Scenario` - text field
- `Functional Area` - text field
- A graph of values over time

Each of these rows (i.e. `Scenario`) has a dimension named `Latest Occurrences`, which has the latest integer value from the graph.

I want to have a checkbox filter on the side of the report named "Show empty scenarios" where if it is checked it shows the scenarios where `Latest Occurrences >= 0`, and if unchecked shows the rows where `Latest Occurrences > 0`. I'm entirely unsure how to implement this in Tableau, does anyone know how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've come up with an answer that allows suppression of non-zero rows, but it's not a checkbox by itself, rather a dropdown with multiple checkboxes. I'll leave this question open in case someone comes up with a way to do that.

My solution, currently, is to create a calculated field called `Scenario Issue Status` with the following definition:

```
IF([Latest Occurrences] > 0)
THEN 'Current issues'
ELSE 'No current issues'
END
```

Then add that as a Filter with "Current Issues" checked and "No current issues" unchecked, make that filter visible, and change the filter type to "Multiple Values (dropdown)". That's about as aesthetic as I can make it, though it's not a simple suppression checkbox.